# Is there software that gives Bluetooth 4.1 compatibility?

Tags: bluetooth

I purchased Bluetooth 4.1 headphones and they work with my iPhone 5, but not with my MacBook Pro Mid 2010 with Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR. I'm assuming this is a hardware issue, but I just wanted to know if there is a piece of software that can get my laptop to become compatible with Bluetooth 4.0 devices.

Comment: apparently it's supposed to "just work"
 http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/news/comments/bluetooth-4.1-announced-as-free-u pdate-for-4.0-devices

Comment: It should work natively with backwards compatibility but maybe your headphones require aptX or A2DP to function. You could always purchase a small, cheap USB Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It turns out that my Equalizer preset was the cause of the sound distortion. It's odd because I never got distorted sound on wired earphones because of EQ settings so it never occurred to me that this would be the case until I started experimenting.